# Implementing AJAX with rjs in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

So let's say you want to add some ajax with rjs and the element that you want to asynchronously add html to is a partial within a partial, meaning that your home view renders a partial in your shared folder, and then that partial renders another partial in your shared folder. How do you account for this in your .rjs file when you call `page.insert_html :bottom, :partial =>...` and also how do you account for this in your home view and both partials?

Answer (score 0):

`page.insert_html` doesn't consider whether the original source of the HTML was a partial or not - you only need to give it a DOM ID (ie `<div id="foo">`) for it to use as the reference point for the insertion.

If you know where you want to insert the HTML via AJAX, make the element has an `id` and use it as an argument to `page.insert_html`

---

Here's an example. Assuming that you have a view that renders the following:

```
<div id="div_tag_in_home_page">
  <%= render :partial => "shared/container" %>
</div>
```

And these partials:

```
<!-- app/views/shared/_container.html.erb -->
<div id="container_div">
  <%= render :partial => "shared/sub_container" %>
</div>

<!-- app/views/shared/_sub_container.html.erb -->
<div id="sub_container_div">
  Some Content That Needs Appending
</div>
```

Which, when rendered, gives you this:

```
<div id="div_tag_in_home_page">
  <!-- app/views/shared/_container.html.erb -->
  <div id="container_div">
    <!-- app/views/shared/_sub_container.html.erb -->
    <div id="sub_container_div">
      Some Content That Needs Appending
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To add content to `#sub_conainer_div` using a partial named `app/views/shared/_additional_content.html.erb`, you would use:

```
page.insert_html :bottom, 'sub_container_div', :partial => 'shared/additional_content'
```

Comment: yes i know, that's why I left the end of `page.insert_html` blank. I wanted to know where I add the `id` to: the home page, the first partial, or the partial within the partial?

Comment: That depends. Which partial contains the opening HTML tag that you want to add the content to?

Comment: well the first <tr> tag is in the partial within the partial. do I use the partial name as "shared/partial"?

Comment: hang on, I'll put together an example.

Comment: thanks. I think I fixed the `id` issue, but now there's suddenly an `undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass` I think it's in the partial for some reason...

Comment: If your partial contains references to instance variables, you need to make sure they're declared in your controller before you render them.

Comment: I'm still not sure whats going wrong. Mind taking a look at my code? https://github.com/meltzerj/sample_app  The original view is on the homepage, and the partials are the feed and feed_item partials. The controller is the micropost controller.

Comment: Aha. Okay. Add `id="feed_items"` to the `<table>` in `app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb`, then change your `insert_html` call to `page.insert_html :bottom, :feed_items, :partial => 'shared/feed_item', :object => @micropost`

Comment: ok I made the changes but there's still an error. I pushed this new version to github.

Comment: It's `RJS error:`

`TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null` in a popup window

Comment: Try `page.insert_html :bottom, 'feed_items', :partial => 'shared/feed_item', :object => @micropost`

Comment: There's still the same error. Feel free to fork the code from github and play around with it yourself.